# Unit Test foreign key constraints in Django models

Tags: python, django, validation, unit-testing

I have 2 models defined, one of which is referenced to other via foreign key relation. I want to write unit tests to ensure this relationship.

```
class X(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique = True)

class Y(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(X)
```

and in tests I have

```
class TestY(TestCase):
    x = X.objects.create(name="test1")
    x.save()
    y = Y(event=X.objects.create(name="test2"))
    with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
        if y.full_clean()
            y.save()

    self.assert(0,Y.objects.filter(event__name="test2").count)
```

This says test failed, `ValidationError` not raised.

Also, how should I test ValueError in case of field is not allowed to be null. `self.assertRaises(ValueError)` does not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
class TestY(TestCase):

    def test_model_relation(self):
        x = X.objects.create(name="test1")
        y = Y(event=X.objects.create(name="test2"))
        y.full_clean()  # `event` correctly set. This should pass
        y.save()
        self.assertEqual(Y.objects.filter(event__name="test2").count(), 1)

    def test_model_relation__event_missing(self):
        x = X.objects.create(name="test1")
        y = Y()  # Y without `event` set
        with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
            y.full_clean()
            y.save()
        self.assertEqual(Y.objects.filter(event__name="test2").count(), 0)
```

BTW, you should specify test in test methods (method whose name starts with `test`), not in  class body.

Comment: For first case, i.e., foreign Key validation, `assertEqual` should be with `0`. Because Object of X with name = "test2" does not exist and hence `y.full_clean()` should not pass.

Comment: @user3490695, It should pass because `X.objects.create(name="test2")` creates a `X` instance with `test2="test2"`

Comment: Ah.. Got it, How do I actually test for entering such an object of X which does not exist i.e., we give such a parameter to event which does not exist in X. Basically, not using `.create()`

Comment: @user3490695, Sorry, I don't get your intention.

Comment: Let's say `x1 = X(name="test1").create` and `x2 = X(name="test2")` . Now x1 is entered in the DB and x2 is just a simple object of class X, So if I try to enter x2 as a parameter to event attribute in class Y, It should not happen because it will violate the foreign key constraint. This is what I want to test, How do I do this ?

Comment: exactly, this is what i wanted. Thanks :)