# Unittest a Django model Clean method

Tags: python, unit-testing, django-models

I'm working on a simple Django social media project and I'm trying to create a unittest to verify that a User cannot like a post that they created. I want to do one of the following

- Write a unittest to test a clean method of a model

or

- <s>Write a CheckConstraint to prevent a User and Post creator from being the same</s>  Can't create a Check on a related model - https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/checkconstraint-involving-related-model/5351

##### My Model

In my model I have a UniqueConstraint to prevent a user from liking a post more than once. I initially tried to create a CheckConstraint to prevent a user from like their own post, but couldn't figure out how to do that. An alternative I came upon was to create a clean method that achieved the same goal.

```
# From models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="creator")
    content = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date posted', default=timezone.now)

class Like(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="likes")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    like_unlike = models.BooleanField(choices=BOOL_CHOICES)


    def clean(self):
        """Prevent User from liking/unliking their own post"""
        if self.user == self.post.creator:
            raise ValidationError(_("User cannot like/unlike their own post"))

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            # Prevent a user from liking/unliking the same post twice
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['user', 'post'], name="unique like"),
        ]
```

##### My Unittests

When creating my unittests I have been able to test the unique constraint but unable to successfully test the clean method. My expectation was that when I attempt to create a Like entry with a User the same as the Post creator that I would raise an error. I used `Like.objects.create`
and when that didn't work, tried assigning `Like()` to a variable and assigned it's values before calling save on it. However both ways seem to bypasses the clean method when it saves to the databases.

```
# From test_models.py
class LikeTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        User.objects.create(username="john", email="john@email.com")
        user = User.objects.create(username="mary", email="mary@email.com")
        Post.objects.create(creator=user, content=f"post-1", pub_date=timezone.now())        

    def test_cannot_like_post_multiple_times(self):
        """Verify user cannot like a post more than once"""
        post = Post.objects.get(id=1)
        user = User.objects.get(name="john")
        Like.objects.create(post=post, user=user, like_unlike=True)
        with self.assertRaises(IntegrityError):
            Like.objects.create(post=post, user=user, like_unlike=True)

    def test_cannot_like_own_post_1(self):
        """Verify user cannot like their own post"""
        post = Post.objects.get(id=1)
        like = Like()
        like = Like.objects(post=post, user=post.creator, like_unlike=True)
        like.save()

    def test_cannot_like_own_post_2(self):
        """Verify user cannot like their own post"""
        post = Post.objects.get(id=1)
        Like.objects.create(post=post, user=post.creator, like_unlike=True)
```

Comment: From this it seems that Django/SQL doesn't let you do a check on a related model
https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/checkconstraint-involving-related-model/5351

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24972430/unit-test-foreign-key-constraints-in-django-models) the key was to call `full_clean()` on the model object. My test then became

```
    def test_cannot_like_own_post(self):
        """Verify user cannot like their own post"""
        post = Post.objects.get(id=1)
        with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
            like = Like(post=post, user=post.creator, like_unlike=True)
            like.full_clean()
```